# "all goroutines are asleep - deadlock! Exit status 2" error in a printer-receiver program

Tags: go, channel

I am trying to create a simple program to learn channels in Go.
But I´m running in to a deadlock error, which I can´t figure out

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func printer(c chan int) {
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        c <- i
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
    }
}

func reciever(c chan int) {
    for {
        recievedMsg := <-c
        fmt.Println(recievedMsg)
    }
}

func main() {
    newChanel := make(chan int)
    printer(newChanel)
    reciever(newChanel)
}
```

My initial thoughts was something about the Sleep function, but even if I don´t include this I still run into this error and exit message.
Can anyone give some hints on how to solve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need two execution threads because now there is no way for the `reciever` function to be called as you never leave the `printer` function. You need to execute one of them on a separate goroutine.

You should also `close` the channel and use the `range` operator in your loop, so that it ends when the channel is closed.

So I propose you this code :

```
func printer(c chan int) {
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        c <- i
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
    }
    close(c)
}

func reciever(c chan int) {
    for recievedMsg := range c {
        fmt.Println(recievedMsg)
    }
}

func main() {
    newChanel := make(chan int)
    go printer(newChanel)
    reciever(newChanel)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I modified it according to your tips, and all the numbers from 0 - 9 prints but then I get the same error after that. I also added:    var input string
fmt.Scanln(&input) but I get the same error after the numbers are printed. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I added ´go reciever´in addition to making the printer a go routine, and then it prints 0 - 9 without errors.

Comment: I edited to precise how you should close the channel and end reception when channel is closed. It seems cleaner (and more reusable).